# emscripten compiled program exceeds chrome memory on windows, with developer tools open the program runs fine

Tags: google-chrome, emscripten

We have a larger C-program compiled with emscripten (and ASYNCIFY enabled).
The program runs fine with Chrome on Mac, on Windows the page comes up, but eats constantly memory up to 6GB, then the page dies with "Aw, Snap!".
However if I open the developer tools beforehand and then type the application url into the address bar the application runs without problems (in the range of 400MB). Same for MS-Edge on Windows.
Does that ring a bell to someone ?
In the dev console nothing is visible so far what might cause the issue.
Any hint how to find the cause would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The problem above did arise with compiling with `-O1` (and we had to choose `-O1` because with no optimization we did run into another quirk:

`failed to asynchronously prepare wasm: CompileError: WebAssembly.Module doesn't parse at byte 4: Function's number of locals is too big 108469 maximum 50000, in function at index 4350 [Warning] Aborted(CompileError: WebAssembly.Module doesn't parse at byte 4: Function's number of locals is too big 108469 maximum 50000, in function at index 4350)`

,see my other question here [too many locals to run liveness analysis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71468841/too-many-locals-to-run-liveness-analysis)

)

We ended up compiling with `-Os`, this did solve both problems so far for us. It isn't really satisfying however to operate with optimization options like being in a mine field....